# Index was out of range and must be non negtive and less than the size of collection

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview1 which has 5 columns, I add to that gridview items from  datagridview2, and nothing wrong with that, now when I try to take these values from Datagridview1 using 2 denominational for loop, to insert it into my sql db, it shows this error.

Index was out of range. must be non-negtive and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name index.

I hope I explained it well.

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try

            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source = OMAR\MSSQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=AccountsC20;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ofamo;"
            con.Open()
            cmd.Connection = con



            Dim Selected = ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()
            If Selected = "0" Then
                MessageBox.Show("Make sure to select a valued product")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show((TextBox4.Text) + 1)

                For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1

                    For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1

                        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into SInvoice  Values('SIV-" & (TextBox4.Text) + 1 & "',0," & j + 1 & ",(select nodeno from productmast where arabic_name= '" & Selected & "')," & DataGridView1.Item(i, 2).Value & ",0.000000,'2019-04-04 13:40:00'," & DataGridView1.Item(i, 4).Value & "," & DataGridView1.Item(i, 3).Value & ",'',0,1,1,1,1,'04/04/2019 13:39:44','',1.000000,1,0,'','b',0.000000,5,0.000000," & DataGridView1.Item(i, 3).Value & ",'Nos',1.000000,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',0,3,'" & Label4.Text & "',1,1,1,1,1,1,0.000000)"
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    Next


                Next
```

Comment: if you have the AllowUsersToAddRows set to true on your datagridview, then you have the edit row. If that is the case, you would need to -2 from your rowcount.

Answer (score 0):

What way are you filling your datagridview either 1 or 2? if you are using likes of a datatable or that you could do this transfering to sql database very easily and quickly using `sqlbulkcopy`, but I dont know if you want it that way or if you use datatable etc.

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    For j = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1....
```

Try use the for each loop see if it makes a difference

Comment: I'm filling datagridview1 of data coming from 2 listboxes + datagridview2 which they are connected to a database through dataset , making a an Sales invoice containing prices names total etc. I don't have any idea about sqlbulkcopy, but my method should work i guess!

Comment: yeah so far to me it looks like it generally should work especially in relation to the error you are receiving

Comment: Same here, if AllowUserToAddRows is true, then you would need to ensure the current row is not the newrow (the row at the bottom of the datagridview that allows users to keep adding). `If Not row.IsEditRow Then` before trying to access your columns.